# how to get row data on MDDataTable when we click on row without checking the checkbox

Tags: python, kivy, kivymd

I want to get the row data when i click on one row in my MDDataTable without checking the checkbox

```
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivy.metrics import dp
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivymd.uix.datatables import MDDataTable
from kivymd.uix.boxlayout import MDBoxLayout
Builder.load_string(
"""
<StudentNote>:
    spacing: 10
    padding: 5
    BoxLayout:
        size_hint_y: .1
        spacing: 5
        MDLabel:
            text: 'Nom' 
            size_hint_x: .4
        TextInput:
            id: nom
            hint_text: "Entrez le nom de l'eleve"
        MDLabel:
            text: 'Note'
            size_hint_x: .4
        TextInput:
            id: note
            hint_text: "Entrez la note de l'eleve"
        Button:
            text: 'Valider'
            size_hint_x: .4
            on_press: root.add_table()
    BoxLayout:
        id: tablebox
    BoxLayout:
        size_hint_y: .1
        Button: 
            text: 'Supprimer'
            on_press: root.delete_row()
        Button:
            text: 'Modifier'
            on_press: root.update_row()


"""

    )

class StudentNote(MDBoxLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(StudentNote, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.orientation = 'vertical'
        self.table = MDDataTable(check=True, column_data = [('N°', dp(25)),('Nom', dp(60)),('Note', dp(30)),])
        self.table.bind(on_row_press=self.on_row_press)
        self.table.bind(on_check_press=self.on_check_press)
        self.ids.tablebox.add_widget(self.table)

    def add_table(self):
        
        if self.table.row_data == []:
            data = ('1',self.ids.nom.text, self.ids.note.text)
            self.table.row_data.append(data)
        else:
            last_data = self.table.row_data[len(self.table.row_data)-1]
            number = str(eval('{}+1'.format(last_data[0])))
            data = (number,self.ids.nom.text, self.ids.note.text)
            self.table.row_data.append(data)
        self.ids.nom.text = ''
        self.ids.note.text = ''
        print (self.table.row_data)

    def on_row_press(self,instance_table, instance_row):
        """Called when a table row is clicked."""
        print(row)

    def on_check_press(self, instance_table, current_row):
        """Called when the check box in the table row is checked."""
        self.select_data= current_row
        print(tuple(current_row))
    def delete_row(self):
        try:
            self.table.row_data.remove(tuple(self.select_data))
        except:
            pass

    def update_row(self):
        self.ids.nom.text = self.select_data[0]
        self.ids.note.text = self.select_data[1]
        try:
            self.table.row_data.remove(tuple(self.select_data))
        except:
            pass 


class NoteApp(MDApp):
    def build(self):
        return StudentNote()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    NoteApp().run()
```

How to do this in this code. I want to get one row data without checking the checkbox

i try this, but it don't work well

```
def on_row_press(self,instance_table, instance_row):
        """Called when a table row is clicked."""
        print(instance_table.row_data)
```

Comment: Please don't fill your question with repeated nonsense in order to circumvent the rules of [SO].

Comment: okay, i am sorry for this

Comment: I think your code will work, but your posted code has no rows, only column headers.

Comment: I use the TextInput for fill the Table